# Help Integrating Trig

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I was doing an FP3 question and got stumped on an integral, had a look at the mark scheme and they made this jump:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{2-2\cos(x)} dx=2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\frac{x}{2})dx$$
Could someone please explain this to me because I can't for the life of me see where its come from
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recall
$$
\frac{1-\cos x}{2}=\sin^2\frac{x}{2}
$$
If $0\le x\le2\pi$, then $0\le x/2\le\pi$, so $\sin(x/2)\ge0$ and therefore
$$
\sqrt{2-2\cos x}=2\sin\frac{x}{2}
$$
So your integral becomes
$$
2\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\frac{x}{2}\,dx=2\Bigl[-2\cos\frac{x}{2}\Bigr]_0^{2\pi}=8
$$
The suggested $\pi/2$ is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: we get $$\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right)=\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

When you see something like this, you should check a trigonometric identity table, keeping in mind that the exact form may be slightly different. (i.e., a 1/2 on one side may have been moved to the other as a 2, or a square root on one side may have been moved to the other as a square)

Regardless, this is likely what you are looking for: $2sin^2(x/2) = 1 - cos(x)$. However, with some manipulation, we find $2sin(x/2) = \sqrt{2 - 2cos(x)}$, which is more directly applicable.

The bounds of integration present a different problem. I don't see any way you can get those to make sense. I question your source on that point.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now - thanks for your help. Not sure what's going on with the bounds, they change back in the next line of the mark scheme so I'm guessing its just a typo

Comment: If you add a backslash before trigonometric function name, it will be rendered in an upright font and look like a symbol with appropriate spacing: `\cos x` → $\cos x$ instead of a chain of italic letters: `cos x` → $cos x$, looking rather like a multiplication $c\cdot o\cdot s\cdot x$. You also won't need parentheses around $x$ then. :)